# Validate Google idToken - certificate verification fails using RSACryptoServiceProvider

Tags: c#, cryptography, google-signin

I am building login workflow using Google for user. Once user is authenticated, I call GetAuthResponse to get idToken. 
                https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/backend-auth

Now, I need to verify certificate against Google certificate. I am using JwtSecurityToken(C#) for the same. 
                I am referencing for verification -   http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alejacma/archive/2008/06/25/how-to-sign-and-verify-the-signature-with-net-and-a-certificate-c.aspx

Issue is - I always gets false from VerifyHash. As, VerifyHash returns just false without any reason, I am not able to find way to verify whether idToken is 
valid or not. My code is given below

```
            String strID = ""; // idToken received from Google AuthResponse
            JwtSecurityToken token = new JwtSecurityToken(strID);                
            byte[] text = GetHash(token.RawData);
            SHA256Cng sha1 = new SHA256Cng();
            UnicodeEncoding encoding = new UnicodeEncoding();
            byte[] data = encoding.GetBytes(text);
            byte[] hash = sha1.ComputeHash(data);
            byte[] signature = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(token.RawSignature);
            // Modulus and exponent value from https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v2/certs - second set of keys
            String modulus = "uHzGq7cMlx21nydbz9VsW1PItetb9mqvnpLp_8E3Knyk-mjv9DlaPhKGHYlJfHYGzKa2190C5vfsLLb1MIeGfdAv7ftpFsanIWawl8Zo0g-l0m7T2yG_7XerqcVK91lFifeJtgxKI86cPdZkgRy6DaYxMuAwAlhvpi3_UhPvsIwi7M6mxE8nUNpUWodh_YjJNu3wOxKDwbBZuRV2itjY6Z7RjFgJt1CsKF-QjqSVvWjAl0LaCaeMS_8yae0ln5YNeS8rAb6xkmcOuYeyhYsiBzwLRvgpXzEVLjLr631Z99oUHTpP9vWJDpGhfkrClkbmdtZ-ZCwX-eFW6ndd54BJEQ==";
            String exponent = "AQAB";
            modulus = modulus.Replace('-', '+').Replace('_', '/'); // Else it gives Base64 error
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            sb.Append("<RSAKeyValue>");
            sb.Append("<Modulus>");
            sb.Append(modulus);                
            sb.Append("</Modulus>");
            sb.Append("<Exponent>");
            sb.Append(exponent);
            sb.Append("</Exponent>");
            sb.Append("</RSAKeyValue>");
            RSACryptoServiceProvider RSAVerifier = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();                
            RSAVerifier.FromXmlString(sb.ToString());               
            // Verify the signature with the hash                
            return RSAVerifier.VerifyHash(hash, CryptoConfig.MapNameToOID("SHA256"), signature);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to try as done in the [Google+ Token Verification project](https://github.com/googleplus/gplus-verifytoken-csharp) - [this fork](https://github.com/gguuss/gplus-verifytoken-csharp) includes a few minor updates that are still in review.

An alternative approach is to just verify the tokens using Google's token verification endpoints:

```
curl https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v2/tokeninfo?id_token=eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6IjkyNGE0NjA2NDgxM2I5YTA5ZmFjZGJiNzYwZGI5OTMwMWU0ZjBkZjAifQ.eyJpc3MiOiJhY2NvdW50cy5nb29nbGUuY29tIiwic3ViIjoiMTEwNTcwOTc3MjI2ODMwNTc3MjMwIiwiYXpwIjoiMzY0MzgxNDQxMzEwLXRuOGw2ZnY2OWdnOGY3a3VjanJhYTFyZWpmaXRxbGpuLmFwcHMuZ29vZ2xldXNlcmNvbnRlbnQuY29tIiwiYXRfaGFzaCI6IlAzLU1HZTdocWZhUkZ5Si1qcWRidHciLCJhdWQiOiIzNjQzODE0NDEzMTAtdG44bDZmdjY5Z2c4ZjdrdWNqcmFhMXJlamZpdHFsam4uYXBwcy5nb29nbGV1c2VyY29udGVudC5jb20iLCJjX2hhc2giOiJjd3hsdXBUSkc4N2FnbU1pb0tSYUV3IiwiaWF0IjoxNDM0NDcyODc2LCJleHAiOjE0MzQ0NzY0NzZ9.Gz_WljZOV9NphDdClakLstutEKk65PNpEof7mxM2j-AOfVwh-SS0L5uxIaknFOk4-nDGmip42vrPYgNvbQWKZY63XuCs94YQgVVmTNCTJnao1IavtrhYvpDqGuGKdEB3Wemg5sS81pEthdvHwyxfwLPYukIhT8-u4ESfbFacsRtR77QRIOk-iLJAVYWTROJ05Gpa-EkTunEBVmZyYetbMfSoYkbwFKxYOlHLY-ENz_XfHTGhYhb-GyGrrw0r4FyHb81IWJ6Jf-7w6y3RiUJik7kYRkvnFouXUFSm8GBwxsioi9AAkavUWUk27s15Kcv-_hkPXzVrW5SvR1zoTI_IMw
```

Comment: Thanks class for the response. I believe, I will go with  Google's token verification endpoint as I just discovered that, our client is developing on .net framework 4.0. Google+ token verification project requires .net framework 4.5. Let me know, if there is anything available for 4.0.

Comment: If you have the time, take a look at token validation using Bouncy Castle. If you come up with a solution that works in .net 4.0, please add an issue here: https://github.com/googleplus/gplus-verifytoken-csharp